# How to properly stop testrpc process?

Tags: testrpc

I installed `ethereumjs-testrpc` via `npm` and I start it in my terminal by running `testrpc`. 
`CTRL+C` does not stop it and I'm forced to suspend it with `CTRL+z` and then `kill -9 ...` it every time. 
Is this behavior by design? Is there a way to stop it like any other process?

Fedora 26 user here.

Comment: Fedora sucks, use Ubuntu

Comment: @Nulik easy there. same issue happens in ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to create a **systemctl service**. Please find below the procedure (*root permission required*):

**1. Create a service file**

```
$ vi /etc/systemd/system/testrpc.service
```

**2. Add the content**

```
[Unit]
Description = Start testrpc
After = network.target
[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/bin/testrpc
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

*You might have to change the path of the testrpc executable*

**3. Reload the daemon services and enable testrpc service**

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable testrpc
```

That's done

**Usage**

***Start the service***

```
systemctl start testrpc
```

***Stop the service***

```
systemctl stop testrpc
```

***Restart the service***

```
systemctl restart testrpc
```

***Check the status of the service***

```
systemctl status testrpc

● testrpc.service - Start testrpc
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testrpc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-10-15 11:23:38 UTC; 2s ago
 Main PID: 29880 (node)
    Tasks: 6
   Memory: 817.8M
      CPU: 1.826s
   CGroup: /system.slice/testrpc.service
           └─29880 node /usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/bin/testrpc
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: (5) 59eeef2c9e108c23f24b385d841b8615f14362f1e1c8b413c5caf563c48f70bb
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: (6) 529d71f653a52a26d24263f9967308207a5b6e59111797c0fe423f1909926165
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: (7) f52acfc25e53a52bf493909f58b222dda288c06a01e6922fdc7e38dabb0b7487
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: (8) 6cdebc1efe3d82f30e6242a595cf80eec813252fc25710151e08c1c7b9e26609
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: (9) 4da9f0d0af082f7ad649f082136f0244774d597b34b8d3b492951decb23a8335
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: HD Wallet
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: ==================
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: Mnemonic:      obscure enact cushion throw rabbit flame chest suggest stick library dice three
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
Oct 15 11:23:40 instance-1 testrpc[29880]: Listening on localhost:8545
```

***View `testrpc`'s output***

```
sudo journalctl -u testrpc
```

If you are curious, more info about [Linux systemd here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

Comment: This means that you need to run `watch systemctl status testrpc` to see what `testrpc` is doing.

Comment: You can also find the log into "/var/log/syslog"

Answer (score 1):

The Ctrl-C doesn't work because this interrupt sequence was disabled for the process with termios library.

To terminate the process use:

```
kill -TERM [PID]
```

To pause it, use:

```
kill -STOP [PID] to pause
kill -CONT [PID] to continue
```

`man 7 signal` for more info

Answer (score 1):

alternatively use

```
fuser -k -n tcp 8545
```

8545 is the default port used by testrpc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`:

Press Ctrl-Z, then type:

```
kill %1
```

Answer (score 0):

Find process id using this command

```
ps -ef | grep testrpc

501 28308 27835   0 12:13PM ttys001    0:21.56 node /usr/local/bin/testrpc
```

Then kill this process,

```
kill -9 28308
```